# Как правильно выводить данные, если связаны с одной записью несколько строк в друго таблице

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Есть вот такие таблицы

```
products
   id
   name


products_data
  id
  name
  value
  product_id
```

В products запись

```
1 Монитор 19
```

В products_data записи

```
1 Разрешение экрана 1920x1080 1
2 Количество цветов 500млн    1
3 Выходы            DVI,HDMI  1
```

Вот в чем вопрос. Если у меня в **products** - будет 100 товаров, и к каждому товару будет прикреплено несколько данных из **products_data**, то при выводе информации мне нужно будет:

> 1. Вывести информацию о всех продуктах ( SELECT * FROM `products` )
> 2. В каждом продукте сделать подзапрос - для вывода данных о продукте
>      ( SELECT * FROM products_data WHERE `product_id` = 1;

И вот если выводится 100 продуктов (это будет один запрос) - то нужно будет пройти циклом по всем продуктам, и по ним же сделать еще у **каждого** по одному запросу, чтобы взять данные.
Но если продуктов будет 100 - то и запросов +100 будет.

Это затратно будет как по мне.

Как реализовываются такие задачи?

Comment: что мешает вам получить все необходимые данные одним запросом?

Comment: @Viktorov как получить одним запросом данные так? Я могу вывести все товары, но если у каждого товара еще должно быть 10подстрок, как это реализовать?

Comment: как это реализовать - `JOIN`ом.

Comment: В результате вы получите одну большую таблицу. 1 строка - `товар1, данные из под строки1`. 2 строка `товар1, данные из подстроки2`.

Comment: А ещё вам не нужно `SELECT * FROM products`, используйте простейшую пагинацию при помощи `LIMIT ... OFFSET`

Comment: @svgrafov если реализовать это join-ом - тогда не получится прикрутить LIMIT к запросу, так как неизвестно сколько будет выводить данных из products_data

Comment: @user190134 С подзапросом. Пример за секунду в гугле: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15897271/6335604

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897055/proper-pagination-in-a-join-select/15897271#15897271 Решение по этой ссылке, все получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `JOIN` для соединения с таблицей `products_data` и подзапрос с `LIMIT` для ограничения количества результатов.

```
select * from (select * from products limit 10)  as p
left join products_data pd
   on p.id = pd.product_id
```